# 3d bar plot in python for dataset

Tags: python, bar-chart, visualization

I have a dataframe in the form

```
   'sugar' | 'energy' | 'fat' | 'score'
0 |   0    |     45   |   5   |   60
1 |   80   |     550  |   20  |   20
2 |   30   |     800  |   65  |   5
```

and I would like to make a plot like in the figure.
In the x-axis I would have the range of the value associated to the column on the y-axis. For instance, if my aliment has 45 for sugar, it goes in 30-60. For 60 it should go in 60-100
the z-axis should contain the average score associated to the aliments belonging to one 'box'.
I call 'box' a particular range on the x-axis with a specific column on the y-axis, for instance 20-30 and sugar.

I have no idea how to deal with the x-axis ? Do I need to add columns in my dataset that specify the range of sugar, energy, and fat value?
Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to Stack Overflow. You should look at the `Matplotlib` python module. And nice drawing btw ;)

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.12-three-dimensional-plotting.html , This link might help you

Comment: thanks for the link, my main issue is how to deal with the x-axis, how to make the aliments of my dataset fall into the correct range on the x-axis